# Can't get an EJB to my web app

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, ejb

In eclipse i have one web application project, and one EJB project with one local EJB in it,
They are both added into one EAR Project, When I try to run the server it seems that every thing is working fine, but when I try to lookup the EJB from the servlet using the lookup method i get an exception, I've tried looking throughout the web but I couldn't find any thing that solved my problem.
I'm using JBoss7.1

Server loading:

```
18:16:08,126 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
18:16:08,708 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
18:16:08,766 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
18:16:10,267 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
18:16:10,274 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using     socket-binding (management-http)
18:16:10,283 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
18:16:10,295 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
18:16:10,327 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
18:16:10,352 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200:     Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
18:16:10,366 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31)     JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
18:16:10,430 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA     Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
18:16:10,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool --     27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
18:16:10,554 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating     Naming Subsystem
18:16:10,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101:     Activating Security Subsystem
18:16:10,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating     OSGi Subsystem
18:16:10,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537:     Activating WebServices Extension
18:16:10,864 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox     version=4.0.7.Final
18:16:11,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming     Service
18:16:11,214 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail     session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
18:16:11,557 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting     Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
18:16:11,636 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1)     JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
18:16:11,911 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on         localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
18:16:11,927 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1)     JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
18:16:11,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012:     Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\isgav\Desktop\Java programing\jboss-as-    7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
18:16:11,957 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1)     JBAS015003: Found state.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called     state.ear.dodeploy
18:16:12,013 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on     /127.0.0.1:9999
18:16:12,300 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting     deployment of "state.ear"
18:16:12,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting     deployment of "stateful.jar"
18:16:12,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting     deployment of "statefulWebb.war"
18:16:12,674 INFO      [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread     1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named nums in deployment unit subdeployment "stateful.jar" of     deployment "state.ear" are as follows:

java:global/state/stateful/nums!nums.Numbers
java:app/stateful/nums!nums.Numbers
java:module/nums!nums.Numbers
java:global/state/stateful/nums
java:app/stateful/nums
java:module/nums

18:16:13,221 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3)     Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/statefulWebb'
18:16:14,515 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) Hibernate     Validator 4.2.0.Final
18:16:14,727 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS018210: Registering web context:     /statefulWebb
18:16:14,730 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on     http://127.0.0.1:9990
18:16:14,732 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final     "Brontes" started in 7188ms - Started 220 of 301 services (80 services are passive or on-demand)
18:16:15,609 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed         "state.ear"
```

Exception:

```
18:27:07,982 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.client] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) JBoss EJB Client     version 1.0.5.Final
18:27:07,991 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].    [/statefulWebb].[jsp]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw     exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling     [appName:,modulename:state,distinctname:] combination for invocation context     org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@266c6521
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)     [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119)     [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at     org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)     [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136) [jboss-    ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121) [jboss-    ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getNums(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:137)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-    7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-    1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-    7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)     [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840)     [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622)     [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560)     [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)     [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546) [jsf-    impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at     com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at     com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)     [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100) [jsf-    impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-    2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)     [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at     org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-    7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-    7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

Servlet code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
    pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%@page import="nums.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.naming.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%!  
    private InitialContext ctx;
    public void init(){
    try{
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        ctx=new InitialContext(properties);
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
%>
<% 
    Numbers n=null;
    if(session.isNew()){
        n=(Numbers)ctx.lookup(getLookupName());
        session.setAttribute("numbers",n);
    }else{
        n=(Numbers)session.getAttribute("numbers");
    }
    String cmd=request.getParameter("curr");
    if(cmd!=null){
        if(cmd.equals("exit")){
            n.exit();
            session.invalidate();
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            return;
        }else{
            try{
             System.out.println(n.getTotal());
                n.addNum(Integer.parseInt(cmd));
            }catch(Exception e){
            %>
            <font color="red"><%= n.getTotal() %>Not a number !</font>  
           <%}
        }
    }
%>
<%!
 private String getLookupName() {

    String appName = "";
    String moduleName = "state";
    String distinctName = "";
    String beanName = NumbersBean.class.getSimpleName();

    final String interfaceName = Numbers.class.getName();

    String name = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" +
        distinctName    + "/" + beanName + "!" + interfaceName;
    System.out.println(name);
    return name;
 }
%>
<form action="index.jsp">
    <input type="text" name="curr"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<hr/>
<% if(n!=null&&n.getNums().length>0) {%>
<table border="1">
<% int [] nums=n.getNums();
   for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){%>
   <tr><td><%= i+1 %></td><td><%= nums[i] %></td></tr>
   <%} %>
</table>
<hr/>
Total: <%= n.getTotal() %>
<hr/>
<%} %>
<a href="index.jsp?curr=exit">Start from the beginning</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please, post the interface ejb code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.
It didn't work because it turns out that if you put your project under a EAR file then the appName should be the name of the EAR, So putting the EAR name in the appName seemed to solve my issue

```
String name = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" +
    distinctName    + "/" + beanName + "!" + interfaceName;
```

- :o)~

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you have deployed your EJB to the server. You must have to use `@Remote` annotation to avail the EJB for JNDI lookup. For example:

```
@Remote(CallerRemote.class)
```

Please check the Section "Developing Simple EJB3 Application" and "Developing EJB3 Remote Client" from [this link](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1466)(Only if you haven't check already!).

Comment: it is not mandatory to use a Remote interface to get an EJB reference through JNDI, a bean that exposes a local or no-interface view can also be accessed using this mechanis. Additionally,  in this case the servlet is a Local client (notice that the servlet and ejb are deployed in the same EAR)